# ¿Por qué JS permite declarar dos constantes con el mismo nombre?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Estoy siguiendo un tutorial sobre el framework Express en NodeJs y empieza:

```js
const { Router } = require('express');
const router = Router();
```

Imagino que es porque la primera no es una constante, pero entonces que "estado" tiene esa primera linea antes de declarar la segunda? Por lo que he leído la primera es sólo una forma de sacar el método Router prefabricado que tiene Express. Pero y si luego por casualidad pongo una variable con nombre "Router" daría error? La primera línea es realmente una constante o no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript **no permite declarar dos constantes con el mismo nombre**, hay que recordar que JavaScript es *case sensitive* lo que quiere decir que `null === null` es verdadero, mientras que `null === NULL` dara un error ya que **`NULL`** no está declarado.

En tu primera linea, `Router` **si es una constante** que estás asignando por [`Object destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring), pongo un ejemplo:

```js
const person = {
  name: 'Carlos',
  lastname: 'Proaño',
}
const { name, lastname } = person;

console.log(`${name} ${lastname}`);
```

Que es lo mismo que hacer esto:

```js
const person = {
  name: 'Carlos',
  lastname: 'Proaño',
}
const name = person.name;
const lastname = person.lastname;

console.log(`${name} ${lastname}`);
```

En tu caso en particular estás obteniendo la función `Router` de la librería express, mientras que en la segunda linea estás asignando lo que sea que la función `Router` retorne, otro ejemplo:

```js
const acciones = {
  Hola: () => 'Hola',
  Adios: () => 'Adios',
};

const { Hola } = acciones;
const hola = Hola();
console.log(hola);
```

Answer (score 2):

El utilizar el identificador `const` ayuda a determinar que tipo de datos es, veamos lo siguiente ejemplo

```
"use strict";

const Router = "Soy el Router 1";
const Router = "Soy el router 2";

console.log(Router)
```

Que como resultado me va a dar

> "SyntaxError: Identifier 'Router' has already been declared

Entonces como puedes notar identifica que ambas constantes son la misma por que el nombre así lo determina, para corregir ese punto revisa este ejemplo

```
"use strict";

const Router = "Soy el Router 1";
const router = "Soy el router 2";

console.log(Router)
console.log(router)
```

Me devuelve

```
"Soy el Router 1"
"Soy el router 2"
```

Porque JS es sensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas; entonces vas a evitar la colisión de nombres en este caso específico haciendo uso del identificador para saber si lo que declaras es `const` o no